# Get a php array into a js array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to get a php array made by pg_fetch_all in a javascript array. But when I try to do it, firebug tells me that I'm trying to convert an array to string. Indeed, I don't understand why because both are arrays.

Here is where I create the php array :

```
$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

$sql = "SELECT ".$colonne." FROM public.".$tablevar."";
$res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");

$data = pg_fetch_all($res);
```

And here is my js code :

```
var array_dropdown =[<?php echo $data;?>];
```

And it doesn't work. Please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP Arrays 101: Arrays in a string context are the literal word `Array`:

```
$x = array(1 => 2);
echo $x; // ouputs "Array"
```

You need to use json_encode():

```
var array_dropdown = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```

json_encode guarantees that whatever you pass in to the encode function will be output as syntactically valid javascript. Note the lack of `[]` around the above code - json_encode handles all of that for you.

Comment: Ok, it works (I don't have exactly what I wanted but it works fine ;) ). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume this as your PHP array

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar');
```

The JS part:

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```